# Select which rows are written during SSIS error logging tasks

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, error-logging

If I try to insert two non-distinct rows using SSIS into  a table with a primary key how can I determine which row is written to the table and which one is handled by the error logging task?

For example, I have a destination table with two columns and a primary key constraint and I'm trying to insert two rows from the source table that have the same values but no primary key constraint.

```
(KeyColumn UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, TextColumn VARCHAR(50) NULL)
```

If I have two rows that have the same primary key, trying to insert both would crash the SSIS package but if I add error logging to record the duplicate row I have a 1/2 chance of logging the incorrect record

```
| KeyColumn  |   TextColumn  |
|     1      | 'ValidRecord' |
|     1      |'InvalidRecord'|
|     2      | 'ValidRecord' |
```

Provided I can consistently determine the valid record (eg: `TextColumn` should never contain the text `'Invalid'` ) how can I create a SSIS task to always write the correct record to my SSIS table and send the incorrect record to the logging task?

Comment: Validate that the source data can go into the destination table before ever trying to insert records. This would include detecting duplicate keys in the source and checking to see if the source keys are already in the destination table. Yes, errors still need to be handled in the insert process, but validating the source data will put you ahead in the game.

Comment: The reason I'm posting this is how to handle an exception. This primary key I'm referencing in the simplified example here is actually a compound key from several columns in the source server; It's almost impossible to detect in source. If I could have validated the data in the source table I would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using 2 approaches:

## (1) Using a Script Component

If you need to check the duplicates based on the KeyColumn (first occurence is valid others are invalid), you can use a script component to achieve that.

1. First, Add 1 output column of type `DT_BOOL` (Example Name: Flag)
2. Inside the Script use a similar script:

   ```
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   public class ScriptMain:  
       UserComponent  

   {  

       List<string> lstKey = new List<string>;

       public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(InputBuffer0 Row)  
       {  

           if(!lstKey.Contains(Row.KeyColumn.ToString()){

               lstKey.Add(Row.KeyColumn.ToString());
               Row.Flag = true;

           }else{

               Row.Flag = false;

           }

       }  

   }
   ```
3. Add a conditional split to split rows based on `Flag` column value, using a similar expression:

   ```
   [Flag] == True
   ```
4. Map the `True` path to the destination table and the `False` path to the error logging destination

## (2) Using a conditional split

If you can check if the orw is valid based on the text column, then you can add a conditional split with the following expression:

```
FINDSTRING([TextColumn],'InvalidRecord',1) == True
```

Answer (score 0):

In OLEDb destination editor, there is Rows per batch setting, you can enter 1 in there. Then when SSIS fails you will get the record on which it failed.

On a similar note - 
In the table you provided, the key column cannot have two rows with the same value of 1. You should be able to handle this issue in your staging table.

One addtl. way of handling this is to do a lookup on the key column and divert existing keys to anther task.

Comment: I've already disabled the fast load (automatically sets Rows Per Batch to 1). To clarify, I've already created the error output tasks. The question is where I can determine which rows gets written to the table and which gets logged when there are two duplicate primary keys. Lookup doesn't address this as it handles rows first come, first served rather than by row content.

Comment: I am seeing an inherent contradiction in your approach.. Primary Keys cannot be duplicate. Hence, in etl processes that concern is usually taken care of before you are inserting the rows. I also have limited understanding of the complete scenario. Have you tried creating an error output from destination using redirect row to an error table? Then you can create a stored proc to send email etc from that table..

Comment: I'll update the post to be more clear. This question is what to do when your source has two duplicate values but the destination cannot handle that. The redirected row is actually being set to an exception table, but I didn't include that in the post because I didn't want to over-complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

If you can consistently determine which rows are good vs. bad, you can use a conditional split and write an expression to divert the rows based upon the expression. This is the easiest way out of it.